# Intermittent timeout on SQL Server after migrating HDD toward SSD (on Amazon RDS)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, timeout, amazon-rds

Since I have migrate my SQL Server database instance (hosted on Amazon RDS) from magnetic drive to SSD, I have some intermittent SQL timeout exception like:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Expiration du Timeout. Le délai d'attente s'est écoulé avant la fin de
>   l'opération ou le serveur ne répond pas. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: **The wait operation timed out**

Seems strange while SSD must speed up executed query, no ? My environment:

- 10 C# applications using EF to query the database (NOT CHANGED)
- 1 RDS instance with SQL SERVER 11.0.xxx (CHANGED magnetic drive to SSD)

My database is in READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT mode. All configurations are stricly the same after the migration.

What I have tried:

- Refresh statistics with full scan
- Rebuild index
- Snaphot sp_who2 and executing essions (sys.dm_exec_sessions) before or after the timeout, nothing relevant (no blocking by result, no waiting type result too)

What can I try more to find my problem causing serious random damages to my production environment ?

Comment: maybe something to read https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/582545-ssds-for-sql-server-good-or-bad-idea

Comment: Thx. But if everthing is in memory, how SSD can be worse than magnetic ? Except if we have many sequentiel IO procesing... "SSDs are optimal for random IO, not sequential IO. So you will see a much bigger boost for your data files than you will for log files.". Here my db config : Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER, Recovery=FULL, Version=706, Collation=Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC, SQLSortOrder=0, IsArithmeticAbortEnabled, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoUpdateStatistics, IsFullTextEnabled

Comment: @GuidoG that article wouldn't really be relevant, since EBS SSD volumes are abstracted across multiple physical devices.  The issue here is more likely to be related to the first-touch penalty of volumes created from snapshots, which at last check was still how RDS does volume type conversions... but I am not sufficiently familiar with MSSQL to understand the underlying meaning of the exception.

Comment: @CSharpDevMan I have the exact same problem. Could you find the solution?